# Does there exists such real analytic function? (NBHM 2016)

Tags: complex-analysis

[image: Choose the correct options]

a)Let $f(z)=e^x+iv$ then Cauchy Riemann equation will give us contradiction thus this cannot be true as $e^x=v_y \text{and} 0=v_x$, now $v_x=0 \implies v=g(y)$ and first equation then gives $g'(y)=e^x$ which is not true.

b) is true take the zero function.

c) This is not true since $f$ is entire and bounded thus constant and $f(0)=1 \implies f(z)=1 \quad \forall z\in \Bbb{C} $ but that contradicts $|f(z)|\le e^{-|z|}\quad \forall z$.

Am I correct?

Comment: Why does $f(0)=1 \rightarrow f(z)=1$  $ \forall z \in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: But $f(z)=e^x+iv(x,y)$ might satisfy Cauchy Riemann, so your answer to (a) needs amending.

Comment: @ChristopherHalverson It does if you know that $f$ is constant, as previously concluded.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I somehow missed that when reading it. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sir I've added the details , kindly check

Comment: I suspect (b) meant to ask for whether non-constant analytic functions of this sort exist. :) There are such functions - indeed, if $f$ is entire and bounded on the real axis, then $f(z^2)$ is entire and bounded on the real and imaginary axes.

Comment: In c) how can you say that $f$ is bounded? That inequality is not enough to state that.

Comment: It's not a hard conclusion to make, but the OP should give more details about how he concludes that $f$ is bounded. @K.Power

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't notice the "$|z| \geq 1$" disclaimer. Apologies

Comment: how u upload that question ,,pliz tell me@MathMan

Comment: @lomberlego Hi, when you click on ask question , see there you will get an option of uploading image

Comment: i have tried and upload but t image image is no shown in the screen@maths man

Answer (score 1):

For 1) note that real part of analytic function. must be harmonic but here $e^x$ is not harmonic. Other you have correctly explained

Comment: how is the boundedness explained in part 3)?

Comment: @vidyarthi:see Mathmore's answer...

Answer (score 0):

Explanations for (a) and (b) are correct.

For (c), Observe that $\forall |z| \ge 1$,  $|f(z)| \le e^{-|z|} \lt 1$.

Now we will use the result that the continuous image of compact set is compact.

Consider the set $|z| \le 1$ then this is closed and bounded in $\Bbb C$ and hence compact. As $f$ is entire, the image of this set is also compact and hence closed and bounded.

So $f$ is bounded and entire on $\Bbb C$ $\Rightarrow f$ is constant. Given that $f(0)=1$. Hence $f(z) = 1 \; \forall z \in \Bbb C$. But then $1=|f(2)| \not\le e^{-2}.$ Hence such a function satisfying above properties does not exist.

Comment: Does not the function $f(z)=e^{-|z|}$ satisfy the condition of $(c)$?

Comment: @Babai is $f(z)=e^{-|z|}$ an analytic function?

Comment: @Mathmore:How do made the conclusion that $f$ is entire?

Comment: @PKStyles Any analytic function on $\Bbb C$ is entire(Definition of entire functions). Here $f: \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ is given analytic. Thus it is entire.